# Rails with hello js, functions executing automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hello.js

Im trying to use hello.js with my rails app. I download hello.js from the offical site included the script in the asset file. Then required it my app.js file.

```
//= require users/hello.all
//= require users/hello_ini
```

`hello_ini` is my own file(coffee script)

Setup button in html as follows

```
 <button class= 'btn btn-primary' id= 'backpass' onclick="hello.login('justickets')">SIGN UP / LOGIN</button>
```

I have included two method that I require in hello.init.coffee.

```
hello.init({
  'jts': {
    id: 'jts',
    base: "https://xyz" + "/",
    oauth: {
      version: 2,
      auth: "https://xyz"  + '/dialog/authorize',
      response_type: 'token'
    },
    scope: {
      '*': '*'
    },
    get: {
      'me': 'api/me',
      'token': 'api/'
    }
  }
}, {oauth_proxy: false})




hello.on 'auth.login', (response) ->
  console.log "response"
  return unless response.authResponse and response.authResponse.access_token
  console.log "im here"

  hello('jtk').api('me').then (  userData) =>
    parsedUserData = {
      id: userData.user_id
      firstName: userData.name,
      token: response.authResponse.access_token
    }
    console.log parsedUserData

    #Sending request to login user in rails app
    $.ajax
        url: "/process_data"
        type: "POST"
        data: parsedUserData
        success: (resp) ->
          console.log("success")
          window.opener.location.reload(true);#not working
          window.close()
        # alert("done")
```

The app is opening pop up properly on click of the button. **But it seems that even if i dont click, the method seems to run automatically, everytime i visit the page.**
Also how do I get the original window to referesh the page?

Any suggestions will really be helpful, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Bind the event listener to the login event e.g...

```
<button class= 'btn btn-primary' id= 'backpass' onclick="hello.login('justickets').then(justLoggedInHandler)">SIGN UP / LOGIN</button>
```

The `hello.on('auth.login', eventHandler)` is unspecific and will pickup upon page refresh.

Comment: not working, i changed my button to exactly what you have written. It still works on refresh

Comment: ... you did remember to remove the `hello.on 'auth.login', handler`.